# Which front end SQL client should I use with a Windows front end configured to a Postgresql back end?

Tags: windows, gui, sql, postgresql

I want it to be open source and runs on Windows.  I have a Linux server running Postgres.  Which free application is versatile, easy-to-use and secure?

TOAD is not free.  There are other open-source options that were made for Linux desktops only.  Heidisql seems to have limited support for Postgres.

Comment: There are many admin tools available. The [pgAdmin](https://pgadmin.org) tool is the official tool released by the Postgres team. Any JDBC-based tool will work. You should specify more criteria.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools